# Slowest regulariser for linear regression

Tags: regression, regularization

You are developing a linear regression model that needs to rapidly process large volumes of data. Which of the following regularizers would you NOT want to use if you are primarily concerned with computational speed?

The multiple choice options are: L0, L1, L2, L_infinity, Frobenius norm.

Idea: I would lean toward L2, but since we are restricting to vectors for the weights, L2 is the same Frobenius norm.

Source: interview question

Comment: Hint: what's the complexity class of $L_0$ regularization?

Comment: From my understanding that's the number of non zero entries in a vector, so I think linear complexity

Comment: But the task isn't to count how many non-zero entries are in a vector. The task is to estimate the vector that has the lowest regularized loss. How many different binary vectors are there with exactly $n$ elements? How would you go about estimating the $L_0$ regularized model?

Comment: Ah right. About the number of different binary vectors of $n$ elements I would say $2^n$ but I am not sure about estimating the $L_0$

Comment: One way to think about it is to note that the $L_0$ regularization task is very similar to best-subset selection. Another way is outlined here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364097/linear-regression-with-l-0-regularization

Comment: Once you've established the complexity of solving the $L_0$ problem, you can compare it to the complexity of the other problems. I think OP will be able to write your own answer to this question at that point.