# Least squares problem penalising the number of non-zero coefficients

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, regularization

Consider a constrained least squares problem of minimizing $(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)$ subject to a constraint or penalty on the number of non-zero coefficients $\beta_i$. This seems related to LASSO or Ridge regression but is different from either of these. It seems also related to AIC/BIC type criteria but again is not the same. Does this type of problem or something similar appear somewhere in the literature?

Comment: See Statistical Learning with Sparsity, by Hastie, Tibshirani and Wainwright, section 2.9 $l_q$ Penalties and Bayes Estimates: "for $q=0$, the [penalty] term counts the number of nonzero elements ... [which] amounts to best-subset selection ... a nonconvex and combinatorial optimization problem"

Comment: https://hastie.su.domains/StatLearnSparsity/ the PDF is available from the author's website

Comment: @Arian Thanks will check

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If ridge regression is considered to penalize the usual (square) loss according to the $L_2$ norm of the parameter vector and LASSO regression is considered to penalize the loss according to the $L_1$ norm of the parameter vector, then this would be a penalty according to the $L_0$ "norm" of the parameter vector, which is a count of the nonzero elements. I put "norm" in quotes because $L_0$ is not really a norm, but it is norm-ish.

$$
L\bigg(\hat\beta\bigg\vert X, y,\lambda\bigg) = \overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}
\left(
y_i - \overset{p}{\underset{j=0}{\sum}}\left(
\hat\beta_j^TX_{ij}
\right)
\right)^2 +
\lambda\left\vert\left\vert \hat\beta\right\vert\right\vert_0
$$

Ridge and LASSO regression would use $\lambda\left\vert\left\vert \hat\beta\right\vert\right\vert_2$ and $\lambda\left\vert\left\vert \hat\beta\right\vert\right\vert_1$, respectively.

Some of the trouble you might encounter with this is that the above loss function will not be a continuous function of $\hat\beta$ unless $\lambda=0$ (which is just ordinary least squares), since the $L_0$ "norm" abruptly changes as a vector component changes its status of zero or nonzero. Another issue is that computers have trouble declaring a value as being truly zero. For instance, run the following code in R: `(sqrt(2))^2 - 2 == 0`. We all know that $\left(\sqrt 2\right)^2-2=0$, yet my computer says the statement is false. Finally, as is pointed out in the comments, [$L_0$ regularization is $NP$-hard.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/364097/247274)

For a reference in the literature:

[Louizos, Christos, Max Welling, and Diederik P. Kingma. "Learning sparse neural networks through $ L_0 $ regularization." arXiv preprint arXiv:1712.01312 (2017).](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01312)

I found that by running a Google search for "l0 regularization" and would expect that and similar searches to turn up more hits.

Comment: $L_0$ regression is also a hard problem because of its complexity class. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364097/linear-regression-with-l-0-regularization

Comment: Additional information: some efficient algorithms for best subset selection were recently proposed by Rahul Mazumder and colleagues; see publications since 2016 in his [Google Scholar Profile](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=cyCp3pIAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate).